# Invalid Post Req

Tags: java, android, http-post

Given this Code:

```
<form action="/site.php" METHOD="POST">
  <div align="center"><input type="text" name="thing" size=25>&nbsp; 
  <input type="submit" value="Something" name="Submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

How would I find the Post req to satisfy this java statement?

```
BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair(OVERHERE, "Hi");
```

What should OVERHERE be? I tried both "/site.php" and thing unsuccessfully and the error which I got was invalid Post req. Is there something wrong with my choosing or is there something wrong with my actual code?

Or is there Something wrong with my understanding of the Post req?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be ->

```
BasicNameValuePair usernameBasicNameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair("thing", "Hi");
```

The reason is, on form submit `thing` is what passed as post parameter.
So when you send request from android, you need to set Key-Value pair, so above code will send hi as the value of `thing` field of the form.

Comment: Hm... Thanks. Then my code is giving me error incorrectly. Thanks anyhow

Comment: Is it solving the problem?

Comment: It still shows me the error but now the code works... (I can't accept your answer for 4 more minutes sorry.)

Comment: Hahaha...BTW what's the issue?

Comment: I was just trying to make a successfully working HTTP POST in an app. When I finally got the code to not crash the app this error keeps coming. So I was worried if I was confused about what was suppose to put there so thanks.